# MySQL MyISAM does an update statment lock the table and prevent reading?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have MySQL database with a MyISAM structure. I know the update statement locks the table but does the lock prevent reading or just prevent others from inserting, deleting & updating the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-locking.html:

> MySQL uses row-level locking for
>   InnoDB tables, and table-level locking
>   for MyISAM, MEMORY, and MERGE tables.

So you'll have a table-level write-lock, which means only you can access the table according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

```
Only the session that holds the lock can access the table.
```

Comment: Yes, if you mean that this means that another session cannot read the table. You current session can, see second link: "The session that holds the lock can read and write the table. "

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a MySQL expert but if you want to prevent reads have you read about the [`LOCK TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) command?